# In Entity Framework when should I use FirstOrDefaultAsync or FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I am using Entity Framework in my ASP.NET Web API. In a query method, I could either choose to use the standard LINQ method `FirstOrDefault()` or the EF method `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. When is it correct to use one or other of these?

To my knowledge using:

```
var users = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.id == Id);
```

and

```
var users = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.id == Id);
```

will both pause the thread they are running on until the call is returned? The only advantage of the `Async` method is that it can be `Awaited` in an `Async` method. However if that method is also being await then it's irrelevant? Except that you trigger another thread to be created surely?

```
public async Task MethodOneAsync() {
  await MethodTwoAsync();
}

public async Task MethodTwoAsync() {
  await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(..);
  ...
}
```

Is this the same as doing:

```
public async void MethodOneAsync() {
  MethodTwo();
  ... await something else to 'please' the async nature, or remove async all together ...
}

public void MethodTwo() {
  context.Users.FirstOrDefault(..);
  ...
}
```

Thanks, just trying to clear up my own confusion.

Note: This is the example I mean

[image: Async method chain]

[image: Sync method chain]

[image: timings and orders]

These show what I mean by a chain and the timings (9 and 0) are in milliseconds. So the Async methods took longer to run (relatively).

EDIT:
In the comments it has been stated that the reason to do this is it releases the thread, however if the method being called is internal to the server then surely it's releasing one thread just to start the called code another thread?

Comment: `will both pause the thread they are running on until the call is returned?` No. The first approach blocks the thread while waiting for the database to return, tying up a thread that could otherwise be servicing incoming web requests (or other work); the second schedules a continuation to resume after the database bit finishes, freeing up the the current thread to service other requests.

Comment: So I understand that point absolutely, but if you are creating a chain of Async-> Await->Async->Await then the previous method can't continue anyway until the subsequent async method returns surely?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean the thread is blocked.

Comment: Ah I see, so it does release the thread for use elsewhere? Until the continuation is called?

Answer (score 9):

Think about other people!

I joke, but that really *is* the point. The synchronous method will force the thread to sit idle until the results are returned.

The asynchronous method will free up the thread to do other things while waiting. In the case of ASP.NET, for example, the thread could start working on another request for someone else that just came in. That is especially important since ASP.NET has a limited number of threads.

In a desktop app, if you're on the UI thread, it will free up the thread to respond to user input. (I'm sure you've experienced apps freeze up when they go off and do something - that's annoying)

There is a really good Microsoft article about this that should help clear things up: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Cheers that's really helpful thank you! I didn't realise that Await releases the thread for other use, then continues when the task returns! I figured it held the calling thread still because of the await! :)

Comment: I've just realised something though.. yes it releases the calling thread, but another thread is used for the Task created, so the same number of threads is still being used. The only time it makes sense is when you are calling an external service right? Where that service will have its own set of threads?

Comment: The task does not necessarily create another thread. It should only be used for I/O type operations (reading from the network, or the hard drive), where there truly is nothing for the CPU to do while it waits. If you try to use it for CPU processing, there is no benefit other than moving it to another thread (which you may want to do in a desktop app anyway, for example)

Comment: This is a helpful read: [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: That's perfect thank you `there is no benefit other than moving it to another thread` that is what my thought process was, if it's internal then it doesn't change anything. However external I definitely understand that. I will have a read, thank you :)

Comment: Just remember that it's external to the CPU. There is still waiting involved if you're reading the hard drive and other stuff can be done even in that short amount of time. In your example of using ASP.NET and Entity Framework, it makes even more sense to use async whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

Async/Await is not always better.  The dotnet CLR has to manage the threads which produces overhead so if it's a small data table then it will probably be faster to perform .FirstOrDefault().  However if there is an expectation that the call may take a while to produce a result you will want to use .FirstOrDefaultAsync().

Comment: Just remember that "a while" in CPU-land is different than "a while" in the human world. A CPU can do a lot in 100ms.

Comment: God help us when AI robots take over.