# FirstOrDefault or FirstOrDefaultAsync core what to choose

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I still can't find suitable information about FirstOrDefault / FirstOrDefaultAsync, First / FirstAsync and ToList / ToListAsync which one to use. Is it a good practice for everything to be Async. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Such broad questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Generally you want you code to be async. Especially if you are using asp net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it in simple terms, its basically like, say you got some time consuming task to be done.

Two things you can do,

- do it yourself `>>` you got to hold till that task completes
- delegate it to others `>>` others will get back to you with result, so
  you don't have to hold your time there.

In programming, `Async` comes into play to help you in these cases so that you no need to make your main `thread` waiting for something untill it gets complete,
instead can pass the control to other thread by using `async/await`.

`FirstOrDefault` >> use when you already have data with you and then want to return first matched value or default value when no match found.

`First` >> will return first matched value if found else throws error, care to be taken to handle error while using First. Its better to use `FirstOrDefault` instead `First`.

`ToList` >> converts your set of data to a list object.

`Async` version of these is to be used when you got to wait for the data *(could be dboperation/apicall)* and
then you want to perform the respective operation.

Answer (score -1):

> The Task asynchronous programming model (TAP) provides an abstraction over asynchronous code. You write code as a sequence of statements, just like always. You can read that code as though each statement completes before the next begins. The compiler performs many transformations because some of those statements may start work and return a Task that represents the ongoing work.

You can check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

and this is potentialy duplicate [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792631/in-entity-framework-when-should-i-use-firstordefaultasync-or-firstordefault)